# How to get Map<String, String> as return type using mybatis annotations

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

Using annotations in mybatis, can we have return type as normal map ?

Basically, I want something like this

```
@Select("select a, b from tableA")
public Map<String, String> getItems();
```

Where

```
mysql> select * from tableA;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| 1    | a    |
| 2    | b    |
| 3    | c    |
+------+------+

mysql> desc tableA;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| b     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tried this

```
@Select("select a, b from tableA")
@MapKey("a)
public Map<String, String> getItems();
```

but it's giving below exception

```
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'a' in 'class java.lang.String'
```

Comment: i think you are looking for a converter

Comment: not sure what is converter. Can you please briefly explain that

Answer (score 13):

Here is how i do this, without extra method for converting List to Map:

Here is Message class

```
public class Message {
   private String code;
   private String message;
   GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

Mapper

```
@Select("SELECT code, message FROM MESSAGES")
@MapKey("code")
public Map<String, Message> selectAllMessages();
```

Unfortunatly it's impossible to create Map<String, String>

Answer (score 7):

the annotation `@Select("select a, b from tableA")` will return a List of Map where Each map will contain a single entry. You might write a converter for it.

```
public Map<Object,Object> mapFromListOfMap (List<Map> listOfMap ) {
  Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
  for(int i = 0; i < listOfMap.size(); i++) {
    Object key = (Object) listOfMap.get(i).get("a");
    Object value = (Object)listOfMap.get(i).get("b");
    map.put(key, value);
  }
  return map;
}
```

`@Select("select a, b from tableA")` will return something like this

```
List[0] -> Map ((key=>'a',value=>1),((key=>'b',value=>'a')))
List[1] -> Map ((key=>'a',value=>2),((key=>'b',value=>'b')))
List[2] -> Map ((key=>'a',value=>3),((key=>'b',value=>'c')))
```

and the function `mapFromListOfMap` will make it something like this

```
Map ((key=>'1',value=>'a'),(key=>'2',value=>'b'),(key=>'3',value=>'c'))
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am doing right now. Was wondering if mybatis can itself return the map, instead of we doing it.

Answer (score 1):

@MapKey(a) will return a map with your results keyed by a

EDIT: Interesting result. Haven't tried using annotations (use mappers instead) but AFAIK it looks like it expects the map being `HashMap<someA, someB>` where someA has a getter and a setter for "a" (like getA, setA)... you can even use the same class (HashMap

Answer (score 0):

```
 <resultMap id="currencyExchangeMap" type="com.sample.model.CurrencyExchange">
        <result property="currency" column="currency" />
        <result property="exchangeRate" column="usdtolocl" />
</resultMap>
where CurrencyExchange class has fields currency , exchangeRate
<select id="getExchangeRates" resultMap="currencyExchangeMap">
       SELECT
              to_curr as currency ,usdtolocl
       FROM
              emsg_v2.store_exchange_rate
       
</select>

    @MapKey("currency")
    public Map<String,CurrencyExchange> getExchangeRates();
```

Comment: @MapKey("currency")  ,  currecy should have getter and setter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).